# C++ 2D vector and operations

Tags: c++, vector, n-dimensional

How can one create a `2D vector` in C++ and find its `length` and `coordinates`?

In this case, how are the vector elements filled with values?

Thanks.

Comment: A 2D *vector*?  Do you mean *matrix*?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth. Is it the same term? Is it like a `Vector of vectors`(which I mean)? Thanks

Comment: @user: A vector is, by definition, 1D.  A matrix, by definition, is 2D.

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates" in this context?

Comment: This is beginning to look like a guessing game....

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to do matrix computations, use [Boost::uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm). This library has many linear algebra functions and will probably be a lot faster than anything you build by hand.

If you are a masochist and want to stick with `std::vector`, you'll need to do something like the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > matrix;
matrix.resize(10);
matrix[0].resize(20);
// etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of options. The simplest is a primitive 2-dimensional array:

```
int *mat = new int[width * height];
```

To fill it with a specific value you can use `std::fill()`:

```
std::fill(mat, mat + width * height, 42);
```

To fill it with arbitrary values use `std::generate()` or `std::generate_n()`:

```
int fn() { return std::rand(); }

// ...
std::generate(mat, mat + width * height, fn);
```

You will have to remember to `delete` the array when you're done using it:

```
delete[] mat;
```

So it's a good idea to wrap the array in a class, so you don't have to remember to delete it every time you create it:

```
struct matrix {
    matrix(int w, int h);
    matrix(const matrix& m);
    matrix& operator=(const matrix& m);
    void swap(const matrix& m);
    ~matrix();
};

// ...
matrix mat(width, height);
```

But of course, someone has already done the work for you. Take a look at [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

(S)He wants vectors as in physics.

either roll your own as an exercise:

```
class Vector2d
{
  public:
    // basic math (length: pythagorean theorem, coordinates: you are storing those)
  private: float x,y;
};
```

or use libraries like Eigen which have Vector2f defined